# How to determine if current location is root in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

How I can check whether current location in OpenCart is root (`/`)?

I need to do some *hack* in SEO logic (`catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for down-rating! But if read my question a little bit closer, you will see that I mean OpenCart specific decision (using controller logic).
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the requested path (i.e. the URL part after the domain) from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

So basically You'd need to do something like

```
if (empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
    die('THIS IS THE ROOT!');
}
```

If you want to apply your *hack* even for root URL containing *query string*, e.g. `http://myshop.com/?query=string`, then do something similar like this:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (($qmPos = strpos($uri, '?')) !== false) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $qmPos);
}

if (empty($uri) || $uri === '/') {
    die('THIS IS THE ROOT!');
}
```

One special case when you may consider that the home URL is also the root while the URL looks like `http://myshop.com/index.php?route=common/home` has to be treated additionally if you desire this.

Comment: I want do to this not in 'vanilla' php, but using controller variables. Thank you anyway, and sorry for my bad English.